# cin, cout, system не являются однозначными, как убрать ошибки?

Tags: c++

Программа по вычислениям полностью устраивает, она перемножает 2 матрицы     указанного размера с рандомными числами, она запускается и правильно     считает, но показывает, что есть ошибки типа: cin, cout, system не     являются однозначными, всего 17 ошибок, подчеркивает красным эти     операторы, как это убрать?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
int** P1, ** P2, ** P3, n, m;
cout << "Введите кол-во строк матрицы: ";
cin >> n;
cout << "Введите кол-во столбцов матрицы: ";
cin >> m;
P1 = new int* [n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    P1[i] = new int[m];
srand(time(0));
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)  //рандом 1 матрицы
        P1[i][j] = rand() % 10;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cout << endl;                  //вывод 1 матрицы
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        cout << setw(3) << P1[i][j] << "\t";
    }
}
cout << endl;
int k;
cout << "Введите кол-во столбцов 2 матрицы: ";
cin >> k;
P2 = new int* [k];
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    P2[i] = new int[k];
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)  //рандом 2 матрицы
        P2[i][j] = rand() % 10;
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    cout << endl;                  //вывод 2 матрицы
    for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
    {
        cout << setw(3) << P2[i][j] << "\t";
    }
}
cout << endl;
P3 = new int* [n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    P3[i] = new int[k];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)  //умножение матриц
    {
        P3[i][j] = 0;
        for (int z = 0; z < m; z++)
            P3[i][j] = P3[i][j] + P1[i][z] * P2[z][j];
    }
}
cout << endl << "Результат умножения:" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)                     //вывод результата 
 умножения
{
    cout << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        cout << setw(3) << P3[i][j] << "\t";
}
cout << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    delete[] P1[i];
delete[] P1;
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    delete[] P2[i];
delete[] P2;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    delete[] P3 [i];
delete[] P3;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Программа компилируется без ошибок? а что там при этом показывает IDE - это уже вопрос пятнадцатый. На всякий случай - это мое личное мнение :)

Comment: удалить папку .vs или .idea или другую папку IDE temp файлов с закоррапченой подсветкой

Answer (score 3):

Сам постоянно сталкиваюсь с данной проблемой в VS. На практике помогает стереть и снова напечатать строку с пространством имен(В вашем случае:std). Но причины возникновения данной проблемы не знаю. Предполагаю, что это проблема IntelliSense.

Comment: Ответ просто шедевр

Comment: @Andrey Вопрос был: "как убрать ошибки". Мой опыт показывает, что это уберет их. В чем собственно проблема?

Comment: Для предположений есть комментарии

Comment: @Andrey то, что это уберет ошибки - не предположение, а причиной возникновения автор не интересовался.

Answer (score -1):

Я не знаю почему, но ошибки пропали сами, просто запустил на следующий день, исправил только удаление массивов, но здесь вариант программы с правильным удалением, все прошло само, чудеса

Answer (score -1):

Это ошибка проекта, нужно просто код скопировать в новый проект, но сначала надо подключить библиотеки, а потом вставить код